# R - Create categorical variable based on increase or decrease in continuous variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a categorical variable from a continuous variable. I want to assign a 0 if the value decreased from the previous observation and a 1 if the variable increased from the previous observation.

This is in R

Comment: Please show some code. What you did so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diff` to take the difference between successive entries and then just test whether the difference is positive or negative.

```
## Sample data
Continuous = rnorm(20)

CAT = c(0, as.numeric(diff(Continuous) > 0))
```

Comment: This is what I have: econ$Cl01 = ifelse(diff(econ$close)>0,1,0). It looks like it creates the 0 and 1, I do get an error that my data.frame has 164 observations but the new variable only has 163 observations (makes sense because the first observation has no lagged value).

Comment: `c(0, diff(Continuous) > 0)` is simpler.  The initial `0L` ensures that the logical gets cast to integer.

Comment: Changing my ifelse to concatenate created the new variable! Appreciate the help!